# How to import/use ckeditor 5 from online-builder in Vue 3?

Tags: ckeditor, vuejs3

I create custom ckeditor 5 build in https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/ (based on "decoupled component" type), at the end i download zip with files. But what I am supposed to do next how to import it in main.js / package.js and finnaly to component ?

All materials I was able to find are https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/vuejs-v3.html , got decoupled-document preset build working, but wanted to add image resize, so created custom build and am stuck at that point.

Tnx for any response.

Answer (score 7):

This post is maybe longer but its super easy 5min done.

**[2022 updated, still works, just config moved in another file, also people may return there because of higher Vue version ckeditor5 toolbar disappear and update/reinstall is needed]**

This example is for full document type of ckeditor 5, decoupled-document is almost everything You need, just it lacks image-resize, to add it go to https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/ click it all way and add image-resize or all other fun stuff (You do not need premium *Ckfinder*, but You probably need **CKFinder upload adapter** for images uplad which is free), and download zip file, do not forget to pick same type in step 1 as one you will use/install.

Install (like in classic guide - https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/vuejs-v3.html)

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document
```

*(if here because of re-install, just remove package.json @ckeditor lines and run above install command again)*

In main.js

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';

createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .use(CKEditor)
  .mount("#app");
```

In your component

```
import DocumentEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document';
```

Now add config to data, You can find this config generated inside files you got from online-builder generator its copy/paste so **do not freak out** :) . You can find it in **/src/ckeditor.js** in ***defaultConfig***, if you do not set it its possible You'll see an warning about missing "toolbar" options. Do not copy what you see below, use your custom generated config, its only for illustration :

```
 data: function () {
  return{
    editorConfig: {
      ckfinder: {
        uploadUrl: 'https://page.com/api/uploadckeditor'
      },
      toolbar: {
        items: [
          'heading',
          '|',
          'bold',
          'italic',
          'link',
          'bulletedList',
          'numberedList',
          '|',
          'outdent',
          'indent',
          '|',
          'imageUpload',
          'blockQuote',
          'insertTable',
          'mediaEmbed',
          'undo',
          'redo',
          'alignment',
          'codeBlock',
          'fontBackgroundColor',
          'fontColor',
          'fontFamily',
          'fontSize',
          'highlight',
          'horizontalLine',
          'htmlEmbed',
          'imageInsert',
          'pageBreak',
          'removeFormat',
          'strikethrough',
          'underline',
          'style'
        ]
      },
      language: 'cs',
      image: {
        toolbar: [
          'imageTextAlternative',
          'imageStyle:inline',
          'imageStyle:block',
          'imageStyle:side',
          'imageStyle:alignLeft',
          'imageStyle:alignRight',
          'imageStyle:alignCenter',
          'imageStyle:alignBlockLeft',
          'imageStyle:alignBlockRight',
          'linkImage'
        ]
      },
      table: {
        contentToolbar: [
          'tableColumn',
          'tableRow',
          'mergeTableCells',
          'tableCellProperties',
          'tableProperties'
        ]
      },
        fontFamily: {
            options: [
                'default',
                'indieflowerregular',
                'Arial, sans-serif',
                'Verdana, sans-serif',
                'Trebuchet MS',
                'Apple Color Emoji',
                'Segoe UI Emoji',
                'Segoe UI Symbol',
            ]
        },
      licenseKey: ''
    }
  };
}
```

Now use it in component html

```
<ckeditor :editor="editor" @ready="onReady" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
```

Decoupled component ckeditor package need **@ready="onReady"** othervise it will not initialize (classic do not need this)

here is method :

```
methods: {
  onReady( editor )  {
    // Insert the toolbar before the editable area.
    editor.ui.getEditableElement().parentElement.insertBefore(
            editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
            editor.ui.getEditableElement()
    );
  },
```

Ok now You have almost everything done just last **magic thing** to do .
In files you downloaded go to **/build** folder and **COPY** all the files into
"**node_modules@ckeditor\ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document\build**" and override initial decoupled-document. This is key thing to do, even thought it sounds pretty horrible.

Bonus : I wanted to have also image upload so added to config

```
  **ckfinder: {
    uploadUrl: 'http://mypage/api/uploadckeditor'
  },**
```

Here is php side implementation its just basic one wit no error handling

```
$uploaddir = '../www/adminUpload/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['upload']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    //$this->sendJson(array("message"=>"sucess"));
} else {
    //$this->sendJson(array("message"=>"failed"));
}

$returnArray = array();
$returnArray["uploaded"] = true;
$returnArray["url"] = "http://www.mypage.com/adminUpload/".$_FILES['upload']['name'];
header('Content-type: application/json');
$this->sendJson($returnArray);
$this->terminate();
```

For last 2 rows they are Nette php framework specific, just send out $returnArray as json response.

Comment: As of certain vue 3 version, there is conflict with older CKEDITOR 5 version resulting in toolbar not showing at all. So I myself returned to this topic lol ;-) would hug my 2 years older me. Nothing much changed even in 2022, only location of example config in downloaded zip file was moved to separate js file ckeditor.js. Other than that I just removed package,json ckeditor and reinstalled same way as in guide, created zip with online builder, copied it over to npm same way, and used generated config for tools. Seemed most efficient to just drop old install and install anew to latest version.

Comment: I have followed you step and I got this error (Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.editor.create is not a function)

Comment: Hello, try this, https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/issues/146 . Also try to build only with some basic plugins. I think when I did it (was some time ago) i clicked randomly all plugins I liked in web builder, but one of them was breaking stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I integrated CKEDITOR with Vue3.js

Install required packages

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

main.ts

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue'
const app = createApp(App)
app.use( CKEditor ).mount('#app')
```

Then in your component where you wnat to use ckeditor

```
<template>
     <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="data.description"></ckeditor>
</template>
<script>
import {onMounted, reactive, computed} from "vue"
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'

export default{
     name:'Add',
     setup() {
          //....
          const data = reactive({
           description: '',
          })

         return {
             data,
             editor: ClassicEditor
         }
     }
}
</script>
enter code here
```

I faced a problem image uploading inside ckeditor5-build-classic,
for image uploading I'm using Node.js server and S3, here is how returned the json response from Node.js server, `uploaded` flag is more important:

```
 exports.upload_file_ckeditor = async(req, res) => {

     let obj = {
                 "uploaded" : true,
                 "url" : 'http://example.com/upload/xyz.png'
     }

     return  res.send(obj)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If suddenly you use typewritten text vue 3 (ts)
Then do the following

1. Create your own component, for example, an Editor
2. In main.ts import ckeditor and your editor:

> ```
> import Editor from "@core/components/Editor.vue";
>
> import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
>
> app.component('Editor', Editor)
>
> app.use(CKEditor)
> ```

Next, in your Editor, write the following:

```
<template>
  <ckeditor :editor="editor"
            :model-value="content"
            @update:model-value="updateContent"
            :config="editorConfig">

  </ckeditor>
</template>
<script setup>
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

const props = defineProps({
  content: String,
  placeholder: String,
})

const emits = defineEmits(['update:content'])

const editor = ClassicEditor
const editorConfig = {
  
}

const updateContent = (data) => {
  emits('update:content', data)
}


</script>
```

And then use it in your application like this:

```
<editor v-model:content="review"/>
```

This way you will get a flexible state of your text and will be able to easily use your editor throughout the application.

Comment: If u need use custom plugins change  import classicEditor for this : import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';